# Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition - Error 1311, source file not found (Yet it exists!)

Tags: visual-studio, file, installation

I've gotten sick of having multiple Visual Studio Express Editions installed, so I decided to get the Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition... Luckily I haven't yet bought it.

I downloaded the VS2005 Pro Trial from microsoft's website (trust me, this was a hard to find link). I am encountering an error, however:

```
Error 1311.Source file not found: z:\vs\_186_RTL_x86_enu_CRT_Objs.cab. Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
[Retry]   [Cancel]
```

I checked, double-checked, and triple-checked that the file DOES exist.

What I did was download the 2800MB .img file from microsoft's website, used microsoft's VCdControl program to mount it at mount point Z:. It does exist, and all the other files copied from the virtual disk just fine. What is causing this?

P.S.: If you're wondering why I am going through the trouble of using VS2005, it's because I'm stuck using windows on a 300MHz processor / 256MB ram system, running windows 2000 pro. 2005 is the last VS product year that works. Anything newer has either too high requirements, or does not support Windows 2000 any longer.

Thank you so much for the help, in advance.

(Erm, my computer just froze so it's now rebooting. Hopefully it continue where it left off... The screen, keyboard and everything locked me out entirely. Maybe the graphics card got nullified, there was blue lines at the top of the screen. Power button, ftw!)

UPDATE: Due to having to hard reboot, I had to re-start the VS2005 installation. It appears to be installing the Visual Studio 2005 component from scratch again, so it may or may not work this time. If anyone happens to know what caused the original error, it would be much appreciated if you'd post. Thank you! :)

UPDATE 2: Failed, again. Same error as above, missing that darned cab file. It's there, I can see it! >.<

UPDATE 3: I copied the "missing" cab file onto my hard drive from the virtual cd, and tried to extract it myself using a utility called "cabextract". It also claims the file cannot be found, yet it is clearly *right there*!

UPDATE 4: It appears more than one of my cab files are corrupt. I'm md5sum-ing all the files and matching them up with shsmith's md5sum list to determine how corrupt it is. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to copy that file to your local drive?  Maybe there is an error reading the contents rather than finding the file.

Copy the VS folder from the image to your local drive and install from there.

There are a number of pages that discuss similar issues:

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&q=Error+1311+visual+studio+2005&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=

Do you have all the service packs and windows updates installed?  I have a windows 2000 VM and ran the default install of VS2005 and it completed without any problem.  But I had just installed IE6 and then all the available windows updates (had to download IE6 to get WU working).

What is the MD5 of your copy of that cab?  Maybe your image is corrupt.  Here is the MD5 of my copy:

9562459319ee43c046e2f4b0a65d815b *_186_RTL_x86_enu_CRT_Objs.cab

Comment: I was able to copy the cab; trying to extract it, however, gave a similar error as VS2005. My md5sum is... eep! `dcab80971c8594279ed6929ac41ced49  _186_RTL_x86_enu_CRT_Objs.cab` - any ideas on how to replace the cab in the *read-only* disk image? And, can you upload your cabfile? LOL

Comment: you cannot alter the image, so instead copy the vs folder to your hard drive and fix the copy.  i sent you the md5 of the other files in my copy.  if they are mostly different than yours then you may have a different version (there were many different versions of vs 2005).  If they are mostly the same, it may be just a bad download and you got a small amount of corruption.

Comment: Whoa. You're very... resourceful? That was just amazing, most people don't think to look on the person's website and get their e-mail from that. Thanks a ton!